# AngularJS and cookies

Tags: angularjs

There is something I don't completely get with AngularJS and cookies.

I have a url: `https://ajax.foo.bar/helloworld.php`
This url sets a cookie, if the PHP file finds the cookie, the output is something generated by the DB:

```
{
   DbReturnBecauseOfCookie: "foo"
}
```

If I load `https://ajax.foo.bar/helloworld.php` in my browser it gives me: `DbReturnBecauseOfCookie: "foo"` because the cookie is set to the same browser and same url I would assume that using:

```
$http.get(httpUrl)
  .then(function(result){
    console.log( result.data.DbReturnBecauseOfCookie );
....
```

should output `DbReturnBecauseOfCookie: "foo"` too, but it isn't outputting `DbReturnBecauseOfCookie: "bar"`. It's as if the server sees Angular and my open browser tab as two different entities.

*How is that possible? How can I let Angular use the cookie that is set in the browser?*

Comment: Do you call session_start in php for every request?

Comment: My `helloworld.php` is Magento, so: yes

Comment: @KostyaShkryob found it

Answer (score 0):

The problem was CORS. http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-origin-response-header

In my case I'm using NGINX, equivalent answers van be found for NodeJS, Apache etc.

```
location ~ .php$ { ## Execute PHP scripts
        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://ajax.foo.bar';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
            return 204;
         }

         if ($request_method = 'POST') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://ajax.foo.bar';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
         }

         if ($request_method = 'GET') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://ajax.foo.bar';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
         }
...
```